# Sql2012 FOR XML Inconsistent "empty element" Behavior

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have an empty string in a table that I am selecting into XML. Ideally, this will produce an empty element, like `<name />` instead of `<name></name>`.

It seems that if my empty string is the only thing I select, I get the undesired (verbose) empty tag ... but if I select other things, including another empty string (or the same empty string), I get the desirable empty tag ().

Can anyone tell me why this happens? And more importantly, how to control it?

```
declare @table table( TextValue nvarchar(100) )
insert into @table( TextValue ) values ( '' )

select
    ( select t.TextValue name for xml path( '' ), type )
from @table t
for xml path( 'row' ), root( 'root' ), type
/* result:
<root>
  <row>
    <name></name> <!-- select just once, verbose -->
  </row>
</root> 
*/

select
    ( select t.TextValue name for xml path( '' ), type ),
    ( select t.TextValue name for xml path( '' ), type )
from @table t
for xml path( 'row' ), root( 'root' ), type
/* result:
<root>
  <row>
    <name /> <!-- select twice, nice and neat -->
    <name />
  </row>
</root>
*/
```

Thanks!

Comment: It is actually of no meaning at all... If you do not have to pass a very strict schema check, both variations are equally taken as "empty" (this is depending on the datatype you are readings this into. **Missing elements** are considered as `NULL`, but you might use `XSINIL` to enforce the element into the XML with an attribute to mark this as `NULL`... So my question: Why do you need this?

Comment: I looked at your example bit more closely... What are you trying to achieve? You'd never use a sub-select to query a simple column... This is - quite sure - just a sample... So: What is your goal?

Comment: Two reasons. 1) Although they are the same in XML, they are not the same in file diffs. 2) I do not like unexpected results. If there is something that I am doing or not doing that is resulting in this behavior, I would very much like to know what it is.

Comment: Okay, fair point...

Comment: :D It's a curiosity thing more than anything else. I was experimenting (I will be writing a replacement app soon) and wasn't sure why I was getting this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It made me curious too:

That's what I came up with:

If you tell the XML engine to **create** XML it is done the way

- open the element
- fill in the content
- close the element

All of these example lead to `<element></element>`

```
select '' name
for xml path( 'row' )

select '' name
      ,'' name2       
for xml path( 'row' )

select '' name
      ,''
      ,'' name 
for xml path( 'row' )
```

But if the XML-elment was created **before** the XML Engine is dealing with it, the (better) short form is used.

All of them lead to `<element/>`

```
select CAST('<name></name>' AS XML)
for xml path( 'row' )

select CAST('<name/>' AS XML)
for xml path( 'row' )

select (SELECT '' AS name FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
for xml path( 'row' )
```

### UPDATE

You even can combine this

```
select (SELECT '' AS name FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE)
       ,'' AS name
for xml path( 'row' )
```

leads to

```
<row>
  <name />
  <name></name>
</row>
```

### UPDATE 2

I think this has nothing to do with the element name's length. Neither is it bound to the count of columns you call. This is merely bound to: *Is the XML created **this moment** or was it create **before**?*

```
DECLARE @n1 VARCHAR(100)='';
DECLARE @n2 XML='<name></name>';
DECLARE @n3 XML='<name/>';

SELECT @n1 AS name FOR XML PATH('root');
SELECT @n2 FOR XML PATH('root');
SELECT @n3 FOR XML PATH('root');
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into this! I looked at your 3rd "short form" example, it looks 98% similar to mine. The only differences are you are using literal '' instead of selecting it ... and you didn't end with the "type" keyword. I find that if i remove the final "type" keyword, I ALSO get the short form. So this definitely seems to be the culprit. I will have to dig into why ........ Is that what you mean by "existed before"? But even if so, it doesn't explain why selecting the empty string twice (with trailing "type") resulted in short form elements.

Comment: I also tested to see if it was a character count thing ... instead of "name" I typed "namenamenamenamenamenamename" and got the same results. 1 instance with type results in long form, while 2 instances (with or without trailing type) result in short form.

Comment: @emery.noel I don't think, that the count of elements really matters... See my update2